# Haskell Maybe adder without Arguments

Tags: haskell, option-type

I am wondering if it is possible to wirte the Function

```hs
add :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
add Just x = Just (x+1)
add Nothing = Nothing
```

without the `x`. Similar to

```hs
f = Just.(+1)
```

However

```hs
add Just = Just.(+1)
```

throws an error: `Equations for 'add' have different numbers of arguments`.
Can someone please explain me why this does not work?

Comment: you're trying to pattern match, so you have to wrap the `Just x` in parens. `add (Just x) = ...`

Comment: @chase But I want to get rid of the `x` or do I misunderstad you? `add Just x = Just (x+1)` works fine for me.

Comment: Your `add` function is `fmap (1+)`, so `add = fmap (1+)`.

Comment: in addition to @WillemVanOnsem, what you are looking for is the `Functor` type class, which is a generalisation of that behaviour for many other data types. By the way, `add Just x` will be parsed as `(add Just) x` which is nonsense, so you have to explicitly add parenthesis `add (Just x)`. I am saying that because the error you are getting is related to that... which is not related to your question, so you might be missleaded.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pattern match *somewhere* - there's no way to "get the value out" without doing so. You can use some unsafe function, like `fromJust`, but

- it's unsafe - doing a case and pattern matching is better
- it's still doing pattern matching in it, so you're not really avoiding doing it.

The "proper modular" way to do this, would be to write this common pattern as a higher-order function, so that you can reuse it:

- in the `Nothing` case, you return `Nothing`
- in the `Just` case, you return `Just` of *some function* applied to the arg inside

Taking into account the two things above, we reach the following

```hs
maybeMap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
maybeMap _ Nothing = Nothing
maybeMap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

which you can now use to write your desired function:

```hs
add :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
add x = maybeMap (+1) x
-- or we can eta reduce it - taking an argument and calling a function with it is the same as just returning the function directly
add = maybeMap (+1)
```

This function is traditionally called map, because you're *mapping* "the values inside a container" to something else.

This is something that you very often need to do for different "containers" (and some other kinds of things), so we have a type class for it in the standard library (`base`), named after some theoretical things:

```hs
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
instance Functor [] where
  fmap = map
instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap = maybeMap
```

Additionally, the error you're seeing is something else entirely. In Haskell, when writing a function definition, your different cases are not allowed to have different numbers of arguments taken:

```hs
-- not allowed, since in the first case you've taken two args,
-- but in the second you've only taken one.
bla :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
bla 0 y = 42
bla x = id

-- this is fine, in both cases we have two arguments
bla :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
bla 0 y = 42
bla x y = y
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that their error message *really* comes from having the wrong number of arguments. Both equations on the left take one argument (`Just` and `Nothing`). The real problem is that `Just` is not a reasonable argument to take; GHC just gives a confusing error message for our weird RHS because we didn't tell it what type we expected.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter is a `Maybe Int`, hence it is not sufficient to only specify the `Just` data constructor: this data constructor has one parameter `x`. You thus should use `(Just x)`, `(Just _)` or `Just {}` to match where the last two ignore the value wrapped in the `Just` data constructor. But in that case you thus can not access that value.

Your function however is a special case of an [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) with `f ~ Maybe` and as mapping function `(+1)`. Indeed, the `Functor` instance of `Maybe` [is implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1029):

> ```
> instance  Functor Maybe  where
>     fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
>     fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
> ```

You thus can implement `add` as:

```
add :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
add = fmap (1+)
```